# Using Maven property inside TeamCity Build Step

Tags: maven, teamcity

I would like to use a property, which I defined inside my pom.xml. Now I would like to refer to this property value inside my TeamCity Build Step.

At the moment I'm only able to refer the other way around to use a TeamCity property inside Maven.

In particular I want to do a SSH Deployer with a target like *url/path/%maven.output.type%/something* with

```
<properties>
    <!-- Art der Entwicklung -->
    <output.type>testing</output.type>
</properties>
```

What I tried was to define a parameter in TeamCity but I have no idea how to define the value of this parameter.

Is there any way to use this property inside the TeamCity build?

Comment: Have you figured this out? I have the same need.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't figure this out. I think it is just not possible at the moment.

Comment: Meanwhile, I found a solution that I posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a script that will set a teamcity parameter that you can use in a another build step. Here are the build configuration settings I use:

Create a configuration parameter with an empty text value with a name used in the next step (e.g. *outputType*).

Add a build step, with runner type *Command line*:

- Select to run a custom script.
- In the custom script field, enter a script that will extract the value from the pom file, and tell teamcity to set it in the parameter. For example:

  testing=`sed -n 's:.*<output\.type>\(.*\)</output\.type>.*:\1:p' pom.xml`

  echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='outputType' value='$testing']"

This will set the teamcity parameter *outputType* with the value of an element named *output.type* found in the current project pom file.

In another build step, you can use that parameter in a field like, for instance, the target field:

```
somepath/%outputType%
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach.
I forgot to mention that I was forced to use only one build step. Later we decided to use diffrent maven profiles to change the properties.